# PHPUnit 5.2.12 Testcase not found and PHPUnit 5.5.4 does

Tags: php, phpunit, phped

Before writing this I search for this topic with no results about my specific question.

I recently starting using PHPunit. My IDE (PHPED from Nusphere) only supports Phpunit up to version 5.2.12. Something is not working fine because from **command line** the PHPunit reports an error:

Fatal error: Class **'PHPUNIT\Framework\TestCase'** not found in C:\Users\myuser\myproject\testunit\ConfigTest_stackoverflow.php on line 7

The same test with version 5.5.4 works fine. for debuging purpose I use a minimal code (no autoload, no dependences with other files, etc.) I try it with autoload, of course and with version 5.5.4 works fine. the code is the following:

```
use PHPUNIT\Framework\TestCase;


class StackTest extends testcase
{ 
    public function testMod0001T00010_Createconfigfiles() 
    {
       //Here my tests
    }
}
```

> ```
> **For PHPunit 5.5.4 this is the output
> PHPUnit 5.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
> .                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)
> Time: 491 ms, Memory: 15.25MB
> OK (1 test, 0 assertions)**
> ```

Which is the expected.

so, I guess the class definition for test is different for each version of PHPUnit. At the end I can use command line but it is more confortable use it via IDE.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;


class StackTest extends PHPUNIT_Framework_TestCase
{ 
    public function testMod0001T00010_Createconfigfiles() 
    {
       //Here my tests
    }
}
```

Comment: It works from the command line (without use statement). Anyway with my bootstrap script is not working in that version. For the moment, what I do is a little trick via script. Once I open my PHPED v.17 I execute an script which replace phpunit-5.2.12.phar by the new version but with the old name. In that case it works with the IDE using the last version. WHen I exit from the IDE I execute the script again in order to restore the initial state of old file. It is not good enough but at least I can work.